# Show that this matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following exercise:

Show that the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij}=i^{j-1}$, $i,j=1, \dots n$ is invertible.

Do I have to show that the determinant is equal to $0$?

Comment: You mean $\det A\ne 0$?

Comment: Yes...Do I have to show this?

Comment: That's one way to do it. Or you can do row operations to see the echelon form is nonsingular.

Comment: This is a special case of a Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: @TedShifrin How can I find the determinant without knowing the dimension of the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki article on [Vandermonde matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), the determinant of the mentioned matrix would be

$$det = \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n}(j - i)$$

But since $j > i$, the above product will always be positive, i.e. not equal to $0$.